# HTML - Calling Javascript Function with variable?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to do a button and if you click on it then it calls a function called `order()`. So, If I'm trying to do something like this `order("+<script>blablabla</script>+")` then it shows me a error if I type into something between the `"+HERE+"` Why that? Is there any way around it?

Comment: Please post your actual code that we can copy/paste/test (a minimal example which reproduces the issue).

Comment: what is your expected result? can you give an example?

Comment: Because your `<script>` element is not written into the document, and therefore not executed. Why can't you simply declare/define what you want to do using `var order = function() {...};` ?

Comment: Because I am doing it in HTML..

Comment: Nah, I am basically trying to do if you click a button then it calls a function called order, in javascript order looks like this: order(name, amount, total) so I want to "fill" those boxes.. That's why I need to use "+CodeHere+"

Comment: Then do (per the answer below): `<button onclick="order(arg1, arg2, arg3)">This button will call the order() function with 3 arguments</button>` where the arguments are your `name`, `amount`, `total`

Comment: Yeah, but to get arg2 I have to do the "++", but it wont let me. If I do ++ then it throws me error

Comment: Are you creating the element dynamically, and trying to put a variable from the function into the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Why do you *have* to do the `+CODEHERE+`?

Comment: So I can put into there "variable(s)"?

Comment: You don't need to use `+` if you're accessing global variables. Just put the variable names, `onclick="order(name, amount, total)"`

Comment: Please post your HTML and Javascript. It's hard to tell what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hx17jfw4/1/ Explanation is there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do something like this. Maybe change the divs around a bit and add a rounding system. This gives you a live update on the costs when selecting how many keys.
https://jsfiddle.net/8hube9ua/

Throw this under your select,

```
          <span data-val="1.85">1.85</span> <!--How much each key is-->
```

then throw this into the script.

```
<script>
$('#suiface').change(function(){
   var span = $(this).next('span');
   span.text(span.data('val') * parseInt(this.value,10)) //multiplies the cost by the option selected
})
</script>
```

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/hx17jfw4/1 Explanation is there as wel

Comment: Updated it with a possible solution. Seems a little less intrusive to have it show a live price rather than a pop up.

Comment: I had to get the amount which is chosen from the options btw :D

Comment: Also, I wanted to do the function because I would not have only 1 of those boxes. I will have 12 different ones with different names and amounts available

Comment: My bad, was not 100% sure how many you needed or what the actual purpose was for. I assumed it was a buying site and you needed to show them the costs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand, but why don't you write something like this ?

`<button onclick="order()">Blablabla</button>`

Comment: Nah, I am basically trying to do if you click a button then it calls a function called order, in javascript order looks like this: order(name, amount, total) so I want to "fill" those boxes.. That's why I need to use "+CodeHere+"

Comment: still not sure to understand, but what about 
`<button onclick="order('my_name', 2, 8)">Blablabla</button>` ?

In this case, theses _boxes_ are _arguments_

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/hx17jfw4/1 Explanation is there as wel